# add ClickEventHandler to a custom control in a Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In a `DataTemplate`, I have a custom UserControl `MyButton` like the following:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyFileInfo}">
    <Grid>
        <!--Grid Definitions-->
        <!--... other controls-->
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="2">
            <local:MyButton Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Copies, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

How to add a `ClickEventHandler` to `MyButton`? Note that this handler function is not in the codebehind of `MyButton`. Thanks!

Comment: Use `Command` instead.

Comment: @Hamlet do you mean, do `<Button Command="local:MyClass.ClickHandler"/>` inside `MyButton` xaml? but this method is not static; it needs to access data of a specific instance of `MyClass`. could you be more specific?

Comment: You must investigate `Command` concept particularly the `ICommand` interface.